# Microsoft Visual Basic: How to make the program write a line after I press a key in console

Tags: vb.net

Im making a console application and im having problems trying to make the program have a specific function after i press any key.

This is it at the moment:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
    Console.WriteLine("Press a key to continue...")
```

I want to know how I would make it so: once the enter key is pressed the program writes a new line of text saying "Welcome to my game"

Thanks

Comment: The program says "Press a key to continue..." but your text says "once the enter key is pressed" - which one do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Console.ReadLine()`:

```
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
    Console.Write("Press Enter to continue...")
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my game!")
    ' ... more code ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cki As ConsoleKeyInfo

cki = Console.ReadKey()

'At this point cki.key holds the information about the pressed key
'so you could go on like

If cki.Key = ConsoleKey.Enter Then
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my game")
End If
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant "any key" rather than "enter":

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
Console.WriteLine("Press a key to continue...")
Console.ReadKey(True) ' True stops it from showing the pressed key

Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my game!")
```

You might also want to change `Console.BackgroundColor` to make sure there is some contrast if it could have been set to something like ConsoleColor.Yellow previously.